# remove the tick mark but keep the label

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, ticks

I am working on a bar chart. Would like to remove the tick mark on x-axis as shown in the picture. I have tried `xtick = none` but that remove the label completely. So how can I remove the tick marks but keep the labels?[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=Year,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar interval=0.7,
    % xtick = none not good
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,408184) (2011,408348)
         (2010,414870) (2009,412156)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,388950) (2011,393007) 
        (2010,398449) (2009,395972)};
\legend{Men,Women}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Add `xtick style={draw=none}`? Or do you wan the grid line to go, too?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the ticks with `xtick style={draw=none}`, and the grid with `grid=none`. If you want either of them back, just remove the corresponding key.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=Year,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar interval=0.7,xtick style={draw=none},
    grid=none
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,408184) (2011,408348)
         (2010,414870) (2009,412156)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,388950) (2011,393007) 
        (2010,398449) (2009,395972)};
\legend{Men,Women}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can move all labels around as you wish, e.g.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=Year,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar interval=0.7,xtick style={draw=none},
    grid=none,xticklabel style={yshift=0.75ex}
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,408184) (2011,408348)
         (2010,414870) (2009,412156)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(2012,388950) (2011,393007) 
        (2010,398449) (2009,395972)};
\legend{Men,Women}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually not very satisfactory since there is still a noticeable gap between the labels the x-axis. Can I shrink that gap also since the tick mark is gone.

Comment: @user1935724 You can always move things as you like, including labels. I added an example.